# Finding the closed form expression of a function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I have a function $G(x)=1+tr(A^2)x^2+tr(A^4)x^4+\cdots+tr(A^{2n})x^{2n}+\cdots$ where $A$ is a matrix and $tr(A)$ is it's trace. I was wondering how to find a closed form expression of this function? Thanks.

Comment: What is the fourth term in the series?

Comment: @JCAA edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Since $\text{tr}(I_n)=n$, we have
\begin{align}
G(x)&=-n+1+\sum_{n\ge 0}\text{tr}\left(A^{2n}\right)x^{2n}\\
&=-n+1+\sum_{n\ge 0}\text{tr}\left((xA)^{2n}\right)\\
&=-n+1+\text{tr}\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}(xA)^{2n}\right)\\
&=-n+1+\text{tr}\left(\left(I_n-x^2A^2\right)^{-1}\right).\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Denote $A^2$ by $B$ and $x^2$ by $y$. Let $t_k$ be the trace of $B^k$. You need the closed form for the generating series of $t_k$, that is $\sum t_ky^k$.

Notice that $B$ satisfies a Cayley-Hamilton relation $B^n=a_{n-1}B^{n-1}+...+a_0$ for some reals $a_i$. This implies that $t_k$ satisfies the recurrent relation $t_{k+n}=a_{n-1}t_{k+n-1}+...+a_0t_k$ for every $k$ (just multiply the C-H relaion by $B^k$ and take traces of both sides).

Now use the standard method of finding the closed form for the generating series of a sequence given by a recurrent relation. See, for example, [this file](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eaf1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf) or, better, [this file, Theorem 1](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Egunnells/S16/comb/rational.pdf) .